# How to call an item from tuple

Tags: python, tuples

I have the data of video ads list and I want it to be immutable therefore I have printed in tuple form. Below is my code:

```
video_ads_list = (
     {
         "title": "Healthy Living",
         "company": "Health Promotion Board",
         "views": 65423
     },
     {
         "title": "Get a ride, anytime anywhere",
         "company": "GoJek",
         "views": 54323
     },
     {
         "title": "Send money to your friends with GrabPay",
         "company": "Grab",
         "views": 654306
     },
     {
         "title": "GrabEat now delivers nationwide",
         "company": "Grab",
         "views": 5123
     },
     {
         "title": "Get cabs now with GoJekFlash",
         "company": "GoJek",
         "views": 62353
     }
)

print(video_ads_list)
```

With this code I can get the data printed but I can't call certain items such as "views". I need the value of views so that I can do some calculations such as video price etc. 
For example how can I get the views of Healthy Living and Gojek.

Comment: Why are you using a tuple instead of a list?

Comment: Ths doesn't seem like a good way to organize this data. You probably want a nested dictionary of dictionaries or custom class objects

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by call, but since you have a tuple of dictionaries, you can index and then look up what you want.  For example, `video_ads_list[0]["views"]` would return `65423`.

Answer (score 4):

Not 100% what you mean but you can get the value by using

```
print(video_ads_list[2]["views"])
```

This will print the views of item 2:

```
654306
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make a separate dict that maps the video names to the number of views:

```
video_ads_list = (
     {
         "title": "Healthy Living",
         "company": "Health Promotion Board",
         "views": 65423
     },
     ...
)

d = {vid['title']: vid['views'] for vid in video_ads_list}
```

`d` will look like:

```
{'Healthy Living': 65423,
 'Get a ride, anytime anywhere': 54323,
 'Send money to your friends with GrabPay': 654306,
 'GrabEat now delivers nationwide': 5123,
 'Get cabs now with GoJekFlash': 62353}
```

So to get the number of views of `'Healthy Living'`, you write `d['Healthy Living']`.

You can make a companies `dict` like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

companies = defaultdict(int)

for vid in video_ads_list:
    companies[vid['company']] += vid['views']
```

`companies` will be:

```
defaultdict(int, {'Health Promotion Board': 65423, 'GoJek': 116676, 'Grab': 659429})
```

Comment: how would that help with `Gojek` since that is company name?

Answer (score 2):

Your dictionaries are inside a set. in order to access  `"views": 65423`, for example, you first have to tell python which dictionaries he should pick out of the set, in this example it is the first one and afterwards you can pick the wanted key from the dictionary in order to return its value, `video_ads_list[0]['views']`. so if we want to pick `"company": "GoJek"`, you have to enter `video_ads_list[1]['company']`

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `dict` with specified keys and values that you're looking for, and then compare each element of `video_ads_list` with it.

```
specified_fields = {
    'title': "Healthy Living",
    'company': 'GoJek'
}

for i in video_ads_list:
    if any(i[k] == specified_fields[k] for k in specified_fields):
        print(i['title'], i['views'])
```

**Output**

```
Healthy Living 65423
Get a ride, anytime anywhere 54323
Get cabs now with GoJekFlash 62353
```